# Table of keyboard signs with their names

Tags: keyboard

How can I get an entire layout of my keyboard, to find out which key combination leads to which key being displayed?

Using `xmodmap -pke` gives me a name like

```
keycode  13 = 4 dollar 4 dollar onequarter currency
```

But I would prefer to see a `$` than the word dollar. The point is that sometimes, I don't know the name of the key I want to type, but I know how it looks. For example the key ! is called exclaim in xmodmap, but if I did not know this I would never be able to find the key combination to reproduce `!`

A virtual keyboard like onboard does not help, because it only shows the main combinations i.e without Alt, Control etc etc.. There can be many many combinations and I would like it to be displayed, just like `xmodmap`, but with real symbols rather than words.